# What's this flower with many long pink petals?

Tags: identification, flowers

I'm not a gardening person, so I came here for some help.

What's this flower? I'm a photographer and it's in this photo that a client wants for a gardening blog, I think, I need to title it what it is.[image]
<strike>Note this image has been touched up</strike> Have changed it for the original.
Thanks,
-Dan

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a lovely picture, but I think the question is off-topic here. It isn't related to gardening, under the criteria listed in our [What can I ask about here?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Also, it doesn't meet the definition of [identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) questions, which state "Include how it relates to gardening."

Comment: Please tell us what the original colours were if you want a good ID, otherwise I will vote to close the question as too broad or unclear. Some of the aspects noted by @Sue can be solved by rewording the question, but the missing info can't be replaced. As you see, Bamboo can ID this plant very accurately if you add details.

Comment: Thanks Sue and Alina, I believe I have changed the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an Aster of some variety - you say you've touched up the image, so this may not be the exact variety because I don't know if you've changed the colour, but its Aster novae-angliae, possibly the variety 'Barrs Pink', though there are probably somewhere towards a hundred  specific varieties of this plant. If you have altered the colours,  it's probably best to stick to Aster novae-angliae and not give a varietal name.

UPDATE: Now that I think about it, it could be Aster novi-belgii, another group of Asters... so you might just want to stick to the name Aster since I can't identify the exact variety.

Comment: It's worth noting that the genus has been changed to Symphyotrichum.  I'm not sure how long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, New England asters have fuzzy-ish leaves and smell like licorice when their leaves are crushed; they also clump. New York asters have smooth leaves and are stoloniferous.